# Anything is common in ml kit? that return same value when similar faces images detect or recognize using ml kit?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I want group similar faces using ml kit but i don't have anything that i use and track common id and save into database

I have recently tried tensor flow lite for embedding bitmap value and after using DBSCAN algorithm for clustering or grouping similar faces images